# Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1' at line 1

Tags: mysql

### Error ID: 1064
Callback: OnPlayerUseCarStorage
Query: SELECT id FROM vehicles WHERE ownerid = 15589 LIMIT -1, 1

```
switch(dialogid)
    {
        case DIALOG_CARSTORAGE:
        {
            if(response)
            {
                mysql_format(connectionID, queryBuffer, sizeof(queryBuffer), "SELECT id FROM vehicles WHERE ownerid = %i LIMIT %i, 1", PlayerInfo[playerid][pID], listitem);
                mysql_tquery(connectionID, queryBuffer, "OnPlayerUseCarStorage", "i", playerid);
            }
        }
---------------------------------------------------
forward OnPlayerUseCarStorage(playerid);
public OnPlayerUseCarStorage(playerid)
{
    new vehicleid = GetVehicleLinkedID(cache_get_field_content_int(0, "id"));

    if(vehicleid != INVALID_VEHICLE_ID)
    {
        if(IsVehicleOccupied(vehicleid) && GetVehicleDriver(vehicleid) != playerid)
        {
            SCM(playerid, COLOR_SYNTAX, "This vehicle is occupied.");
        }
        else //SCM(playerid, COLOR_SYNTAX, "This command is disabled.");
        {
            new
                Float:health;

            GetVehicleHealth(vehicleid, health);

            if(health < 600.0)
            {
                SCM(playerid, COLOR_SYNTAX, "This vehicle is too damaged to be despawned.");
            }
            else
            {
                SM(playerid, COLOR_AQUA, "Your "SVRCLR"%s{CCFFFF} which is located in %s has been despawned.", GetVehicleName(vehicleid), GetVehicleZoneName(vehicleid));
                DespawnVehicle(vehicleid);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_format(connectionID, queryBuffer, sizeof(queryBuffer), "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id = %i AND ownerid = %i", cache_get_field_content_int(0, "id"), PlayerInfo[playerid][pID]);
        mysql_tquery(connectionID, queryBuffer, "OnPlayerSpawnVehicle", "ii", playerid, false);
    }
}
```

Would like to ask how to solve this problem I'm not that good in MySQL scripting the owner ID is just an example of ID and I think there is no problem in that

Comment: `LIMIT -1, 1` ? Is that intentional? You should do a check if `%i` returns `<0` then replace it with `0`. I don't think `LIMIT` works with negative offset/row_count.

Comment: LIMIT -1, 1 is the output error and  I think the error but when I run it in MYSQL query seems fine

Comment: You were able to run the query with `LIMIT -1, 1`?